# How to control the depth of \localtablecontents in etoc

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, etoc

Is there a way to control the depth of what is shown by `\localtablecontents`, similarly to how `\setcounter{parttocdepth}{.}` and `\setcounter{minitocdepth}{.}` control the depth in the minitoc package. This would allow on a different depth of what is shown in my MWE for the `\localtableofcontents` of `\part`s and `\chapter`s. In `\part`s for example I would only like to show `\chapter`s and `\section`s not the full depth down to `\subsubsection`s. Also, I notice numbering ceases at the `\section` level, why?

By the way, interworking of `etoc` and `\usepackage{hyperref}` will be the subject of a separate question.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{book}
% MWE 20June16
% COMMENTS: etoc. how to control the depth of \localtablecontents.
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoc}
\begin{document}
%===========
\frontmatter
%===========
% all toc depths: -1=\part, 0=\chapter, 1=\section, 2=\subsection,   3=\subsubsection
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}  % main table of contents, if used
\shorttableofcontents{Summary Contents}{0}
%\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[2]
%===========
\mainmatter
%===========
\part{Part ONE}
%\begingroup
%\let\clearpage\relax  % does not serve the same purpose for \part as it does for \chapter, regardless of whether the \documentclass{..,oneside] parameter is set or not. 
\localtableofcontents
%\endgroup
%\newpage

\chapter{Chap. One}
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\localtableofcontents
\endgroup
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\section*{Introduction}
Introducing the topic of this chapter.
\section{Sec. Alpha}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of this section.
\subsection{Subsec. one}
General comments to all subsubsections of this subsection
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 1}
\lipsum[1]
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 2}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. two}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. Bravo}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of this section.
\subsection{Subsec. three}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. four}
\lipsum[1]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}
\section*{Summary}
Summarizing all topics discussed in this chapter and looking ahead.

\chapter{Chap. Two}
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\localtableofcontents
\endgroup
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\section*{Introduction}
Introducing the topic of this chapter.
\section{Sec. Charlie}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of this section.
\subsection{Subsec. five}
General comments to all subsubsections of this subsection
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 3}
\lipsum[1]
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 4}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. six}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. Delta}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of this section.
\subsection{Subsec. seven}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. eight}
\lipsum[1]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}
\section*{Summary}
Summarizing all topics discussed in this chapter and looking ahead.

\chapter{Chap. Three}
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\localtableofcontents
\endgroup
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\section*{Introduction}
Introducing the topic of this chapter.
\section{Sec. Echo}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of this section.
\subsection{Subsec. nine}
General comments to all subsubsections of this subsection
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 5}
\lipsum[1]
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 6}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. ten}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. Foxtrot}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of this section.
\subsection{Subsec. eleven}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. twelve}
\lipsum[1]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}
\section*{Summary}
Summarizing all topics discussed in this chapter and looking ahead.

\part{Part TWO}
\localtableofcontents
% etc. etc.

\part{Part THREE}
\localtableofcontents
% etc. etc.

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\etocsettocdepth{...}` is what you want, most likely, where `...` stands for the relevant toc-depth. And `etoc` and `hyperref` seem to work together very well, if `hyperref` is loaded **after** `etoc`, not before

Comment: with `etoc` you don't really need `shorttoc`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command `\etocsettocdepth` sets the depth of the ToC for the `\localtableofcontents` and is similar to `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}`, for example. `\etocsettocdepth` is sticky until another call will change the value eventually. If another `tocdepth` is requested in between, `\etocsetnexttocdepth` can be used instead -- this setting is used only for one (i.e. the next) `ToC`.

The numbering of the section etc. can be controlled with `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}`, where `3` means `subsubsection` here.

`hyperref` and `etoc` work together, if `hyperref` is loaded later than `etoc` -- which is a general rule, actually.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{book}
% MWE 20June16
% COMMENTS: etoc. how to control the depth of \localtablecontents.
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
%===========
\frontmatter
%===========
% all toc depths: -1=\part, 0=\chapter, 1=\section, 2=\subsection,   3=\subsubsection
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}  % main table of contents, if used
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
\shorttableofcontents{Summary Contents}{0}
%\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[2]
%===========
\mainmatter
%===========
\part{Part ONE}
%\begingroup
%\let\clearpage\relax  % does not serve the same purpose for \part as it does for \chapter, regardless of whether the \documentclass{..,oneside] parameter is set or not. 
\etocsettocdepth{1}
\localtableofcontents
%\endgroup
%\newpage

\chapter{Chap. One}
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\localtableofcontents
\endgroup
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\section*{Introduction}
Introducing the topic of this chapter.
\section{Sec. Alpha}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of this section.
\subsection{Subsec. one}
General comments to all subsubsections of this subsection
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 1}
\lipsum[1]
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 2}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. two}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. Bravo}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of this section.
\subsection{Subsec. three}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. four}
\lipsum[1]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}
\section*{Summary}
Summarizing all topics discussed in this chapter and looking ahead.

\chapter{Chap. Two}
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\etocsettocdepth{1}
\localtableofcontents
\endgroup
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\section*{Introduction}
Introducing the topic of this chapter.
\section{Sec. Charlie}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of this section.
\subsection{Subsec. five}
General comments to all subsubsections of this subsection
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 3}
\lipsum[1]
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 4}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. six}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. Delta}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of this section.
\subsection{Subsec. seven}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. eight}
\lipsum[1]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}
\section*{Summary}
Summarizing all topics discussed in this chapter and looking ahead.

\chapter{Chap. Three}
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\localtableofcontents
\endgroup
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\section*{Introduction}
Introducing the topic of this chapter.
\section{Sec. Echo}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of this section.
\subsection{Subsec. nine}
General comments to all subsubsections of this subsection
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 5}
\lipsum[1]
\subsubsection{Subsubsec. 6}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. ten}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Sec. Foxtrot}
General comments pertaining to all subsections of this section.
\subsection{Subsec. eleven}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsec. twelve}
\lipsum[1]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}
\section*{Summary}
Summarizing all topics discussed in this chapter and looking ahead.

\part{Part TWO}
\localtableofcontents
% etc. etc.

\part{Part THREE}
\localtableofcontents
% etc. etc.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm. I'll get back to you on the subject of hyperref after some experimenting.

Comment: It is not needed (at least if I trust `etoc`'s manual ;-) ) to load `hyperref` _after_ `etoc`; this being said I concur that as a general rule it is safest to load `hyperref` last among packages.